# Newbie at python running into issues with unsupported operand types?

Tags: python

I keep on getting this error in my code and am unsure about how to go about fixing it, I've attempted to convert key and num into integers to try to fix it but it doesn't work.
Thanks

Code:

```
m = "hi"
key = input("What is the key: ")
while len(key) < 0:
    print("Please enter a key")
    key = input("What is the key: ")
    key=int(key)

print (key, m)

def encrypt(m, key):
    translated=''
    for symbol in m:
         if symbol.isalpha():
             num = ord(symbol)
             print (num)
             num = num+ key
print(encrypt(m, key))
```

and when i run the code i get this:

```
What is the key: 3
3 hi
104
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anon/Documents/test2.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(encrypt(m, key))
  File "C:/Users/anon/Documents/test2.py", line 16, in encrypt
    num = num+ key
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

Comment: Because `num` is `str`, and `key` is `int`. Maybe you need convert  `num` to `int`?

Comment: Wait, seems like `num` is `int` and `key` is `str`.

Comment: And your function doesn't return anything, why are you doing `print(encrypt(m, key))`? And what does `translated=''` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this part of your code:

```
key = input("What is the key: ")
while len(key) < 0:
    print("Please enter a key")
    key = input("What is the key: ")
    key=int(key)
```

If `key` is smaller than `0`, then the `while` loop will run and the `key` will be convert to `int`.

But if the `key` isn't smaller than `0`, the while loop will be skipped. `key=int(key)` will not run so `key` is still `str`.

---

And you can't do something like `str() + int()`. If you did that then Python will raise a `TypeError` that you've got because they're different types. So Python doesn't understand what are you doing. I think you know that.

By the way, if user didn't enter a number(for example, a word), then `int()` function will raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

So the best way is use `try...except` to capture this error and tell user enter a number like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        key = int(input("What is the key: "))
        break # if 'int' raise an error, `break` will not run so the loop will not break.
    except ValueError:
        print('please enter a key')
```

Comment: Thankyou this helped alot! 
(This was just a small section of a much larger piece of code so it might not make sense on its own.)

Comment: @Aslinnl Okay, glad to help :)